# Summary/Cross Tab Using Using Multiple Variables + Percentage Change Columns

Tags: crosstab, gtsummary

I am trying to use gtsummary to count the number of times someone engaged in an action (a; binary variable, yes/no) in a given year (b, continuous variable, ranging from 2002-2020) by various demographic factors (c-z; i.e. race, income, educational attainment) for complex survey data. Is there anyway to do this in gtsummary? Furthermore, is there any way to use gtsummary to generate columns that would provide the percentage change (in absolute and relative terms) between two years for a given demographic factor (i.e. what is the percentage change between 2006 and 2020 in the number of times someone engaged in action "a" for (black/white/hispanic/mixed race) participants?

So far, I'm seeing the tbl_cross function can handle up to two variables, and tbl_svysummary seems equipped for more general summary statistics (i.e. counting the number of (black/white/hispanic) people by whether they engaged in action "a" or not) and not this more granular question I was wondering about.

Any guidance you have here would be much appreciated (and totally understand if this is beyond the scope of the package)! Thank you as always for your awesome work with gtsummary.

Comment: Does tbl_summary not do what you need? http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html

Comment: I don't think so. In the example with tbl_svysummary, the 
"by = " function splits the API variables by whether they met both targets, and the cells are filled with the median values for API in 2000/1999. I'm interested in including a *third* variable (i.e. counting whether someone engaged in action "a" (yes/no), stratified by API in 1999/2000 AND for whether they "Met Both Targets". Make sense? In my example the cells would be filled with counts of "action a", not the median for API and "Met Both Targets".

Comment: I also do not know of any functionality in gtsummary for calculating percentage change between two count columns as well

Comment: For more then 1 stratifying variable, perhaps tbl_strata will be what you need http://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/dev/reference/tbl_strata.html To get percent change, check out add_difference

Comment: If you update the post with an example table, I can perhaps be more precise in recommendations